# Need help adding a role to a user. (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I'm online the bot gives me a role, as soon as I go offline the bot removes that role from me.

When it removes the role, I want the bot to give the role to a specific user. How can I do that?

I have my current code below:

```js
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  const member = newPresence.member;
  if (member.id === 'user.id') {
    if (oldPresence.status !== newPresence.status) {
      var gen = client.channels.cache.get('channel.id');
      if (
        newPresence.status == 'idle' ||
        newPresence.status == 'online' ||
        newPresence.status == 'dnd'
      ) {
        gen.send('online');
        member.roles.add('role.id');
      } else if (newPresence.status === 'offline') {
        gen.send('offline');
        member.roles.remove('role.id');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to add your question :)

Comment: Its in the last sentance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the other member by its ID. `newPresence` has a `guild` property that has a `members` property; by using its `.fetch()` method, you can get the member you want to assign the role to. Once you have this member, you can use `.toles.add()` again. Check the code below:

```js
// use an async function so we don't have to deal with then() methods
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  // move all the variables to the top, it's just easier to maintain
  const channelID = '81023493....0437';
  const roleID = '85193451....5834';
  const mainMemberID = '80412945....3019';
  const secondaryMemberID = '82019504....8541';
  const onlineStatuses = ['idle', 'online', 'dnd'];
  const offlineStatus = 'offline';
  const { member } = newPresence;

  if (member.id !== mainMemberID || oldPresence.status === newPresence.status)
    return;

  try {
    const channel = await client.channels.fetch(channelID);

    if (!channel) return console.log('Channel not found');

    // grab the other member
    const secondaryMember = await newPresence.guild.members.fetch(secondaryMemberID);

    if (onlineStatuses.includes(newPresence.status)) {
      member.roles.add(roleID);
      secondaryMember.roles.remove(roleID);
      channel.send('online');
    }

    if (newPresence.status === offlineStatus) {
      member.roles.remove(roleID);
      secondaryMember.roles.add(roleID);
      channel.send('offline');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what i was lookig for. One small note for anyone who wants to use this, add 

                    const secondaryMember = await   newPresence.guild.members.fetch(secondaryMemberID);
                    secondaryMember.roles.remove(roleID);


above 

 channel.send('online');

Comment: Ah, yes, I've just updated my answer and added it. Thanks